# Row count in aggrid with pagination

Tags: pagination, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using aggrid with pagination(client side).

I need to get the count of rows present in current page.

When i use the below apis it always gives me count of all rows present in all pages.

```
gridApi.paginationGetRowCount()

gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount()

gridApi.paginationProxy.masterRowCount
```

Comment: Have you tried [paginationGetPageSize()](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#pagination)?

Comment: Hi, I think pageSize is the number of rows that need to be displayed in a given page in a paginated aggrid. I need the number of rows that are present. It can be 0 to pageSize(). pageSize() is always constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one you need is `GridApi.paginationGetPageSize()`.

- `GridApi.paginationGetRowCount()` returns total number of rows in all pages.
- `GridApi.getDisplayedRowCount()` returns total number of rows in all pages, plus all expanded rows (when using [Row Grouping](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping) or [Master Detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail)).
- `GridApi.paginationProxy` is a private property and should not be used.

If you want to get the number of rows in current page. You can calculate the `startResult` and `endResult` of that page yourself. The number of rows in the page is `endResult` - `startResult` + 1

```js
const printPagination = () => {
  const currentPage = gridApi.paginationGetCurrentPage();
  const totalPage = gridApi.paginationGetTotalPages();
  const totalResults = gridApi.paginationGetRowCount();
  const pageSize = gridApi.paginationGetPageSize();
  const startResult = currentPage * pageSize + 1;
  const endResult = Math.min(startResult + pageSize - 1, totalResults);

  console.log();
  console.log("Page size:", pageSize);
  console.log("Current page:", currentPage);
  console.log("Total pages:", totalPage);
  console.log("Total results:", totalResults);
  console.log("Start-end:", startResult, endResult);
  console.log("Number of rows in this page:", endResult - startResult + 1);
};
```

### Live Example

The live example below uses React but it should be trivial to convert that code to angular

[image: Edit AgGrid Number Of Rows In Current Page]

Comment: It seems pageSize is the maximum number of rows that can be displayed in a given page in paginated grid.  All the pages except last page will have pageSize number of rows, but the last page in a paginated grid may have minimum of 1 row and a maximum of pageSize rows. I just need that count in the last page.

Comment: I've updated my answer to take into account of the last page

Comment: api.getRenderedNodes().length also seems to be the one that solves the problem. 
I also wanted the count of rows on the current page when filters are applied.I am using a custom pagination nav panel.